# Azure Applicattion Logging not working

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, trace, system.diagnostics

My web app deployed to an Azure App Services (web site) has stopped to log from *System.Diagnostics.Trace*

I'm not sure at which stage it has stopped to fail to log, I suspect might be caused by any package added through Nugget.

I've created a new app from scratch and it logs all the info into file system and into Azure blob storage without any web.config update or adding any package.

How can I find the issue with the System.Diagnostics dll?

Nothing to show really in the web.config, just a default one.

Application logging set in Azure settings for filesystem and blob

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you don't enable the Diagnostics logs in azure web app. System.Diagnostics will not log the information after you deployed the app to azure.

So I suggest you could firstly follow below steps to enable log and try again.

[image]

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log).

Comment: Thanks and sorry, forgot to mention that was set up for filesystem and blob

Comment: This is very strange, if you enable the log azure will auto the error to the file or blob storage. In my side, I couldn't repro your issue. If possible you could share a test project in github for us to repro the issue, then we could find how to solve it.